# It is possible to reconnect a user if we use signInAnonimously?

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase Auth, and I use the `signInAnonimously()` method.

I was wondering if the user delete the app and want to reconnect to with the same account how can I do this ?

I will ask to the user the uid of this last account.

here the method I use to `signInAnonymously()` :

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                Log.i("TAG","tsk :"+task);
                                uid=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                Log.i("TAG","uid :"+uid);
                                createUserInFirestore();
                            }
                            else{
                                Log.i("TAG","fail "+task.getException());
                            }

                        }
                    });
```

If I get the last uid can I reconnect the user ?
thanks

Comment: For that you convert Anonimous user to perment user.

Comment: **I will ask to the user the uid of this last account.** User can't provide you UID.

Comment: @mehulchauhan thanks i will try this way.

Comment: I suggest better use email and password or gmail auth to login for users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase anonymous authentication create temporary anonymous accounts to authenticate with Firebase but anonymous authentication accounts don't persist across application uninstalls. When an application is uninstalled, everything that was saved locally will be deleted, including the anonymous Auth token that identifies that account.

**Unfortunately, there is no easy way to reclaim that token for the user.**